# How to count the number of occurrences in another table with condition in power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, countif, measure

I'm trying to implement in Power BI what I did in an Excel file but I am facing some issues. I would like to manage calculations in Power BI in order to avoid calculation in Excel.

So, I have 3 tables:

- table `PLM`: where we can see some references (column `Name`) that we release every month.
- table `CADTrack`: where we follow the usage of some application --> The objective is to see if we use our application for reference that we release every month
- the table `admin` indicates a number of month that we will need for the calculation

[image]

The final objective is to create a tree map to see the potential and how we cover reference type with our applications.

[image]

I succeed by managing the calculation in Excel by creating two additional columns (in red) in order to define if, for each release reference, an application has been launched in the last 6 month (admin table).

Example: for the last line of the table PLM, we can see that for the reference "1882862X", we have used one time an application in April.

After that, I have uploaded the Excel file in Power BI and created a new measure:

```
CAD Potential =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( PLM[Type] ), PLM[Exist in CAD data] = "Yes" ) * 100
    / COUNTROWS ( RELATEDTABLE ( PLM ) )
```

But I would like to manage the calculation directly in Power BI, the data source has more than 800,000 lines and takes too much time in Excel ;-)

I have seen different posts where are explained how to count occurrence in a different table but as I am novice I did not succeed.

Could you support me in order to optimize the calculation in Power BI, please?

Thanks in advance for the support

Cyrille

Comment: What is your data model in Power-bi. I believe you are missing a relation...It is also confusing to me you have the word Ford_ before the part. Then Power-bi cannot find a relation (the names of columns are also not equal).

Comment: How could I upload the power BI file in order to clarify ?

Comment: And it is because we search in the column PartNumber (table CadTrack) if it contains the Name (Table PLM).